# Case insensitive tab completion in Bash

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, shell

Is there any way to make Bash tab complete case insensitively?

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I am using Mac OS X 10.6

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Update the text in `/etc/inputrc` to include

```
set completion-ignore-case on
```

Then use `^X ^R` to reload the configuration.

Comment: "as well" - `/etc/inputrc` or `~/.inputrc` or a file designated by `INPUTRC` are the only places it can go. Entering that at a Bash prompt won't work.

Comment: whoops! you're right :)

Comment: `^X ^R` to reload `inputrc`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: you can do `bind "set completion-ignore-case on"` from the command line; for, I believe, that terminal session only

Comment: So *that's* what msysgit has but MSYS2 lacks! Here I was trying to find it in e.g. /etc/profile ...

Comment: Writing this to ~/.inputrc breaks the ctrl key functionality. Or am I the only one with this problem?

Comment: if not successful with reload the configuration, can just restart bash

Comment: I'm on macOS and new to bash. How exactly does one "Update the text in /etc/inputrc" ?

Answer (score 126):

<sup>Restructured with the benefit of hindsight to contrast the pros and cons of using `[.]inputrc` vs. `.bash_profile`.

Tip of the hat to [underscore_d](https://superuser.com/users/472201/underscore-d) for his help.</sup>

*Note:* Command-line editing in Bash is provided by the Readline library; customizing it is non-trivial, but well worth learning; its features include the ability to  define custom keyboard shortcuts for inserting predefined snippets of text - see [*Command Line Editing* in the Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Line-Editing.html#Command-Line-Editing)

To *persistently* make tab-completion case-insensitive in Bash:

---

**Option A:** If you either already have:

- an `/etc/inputrc` file (applies system-wide, modification requires `sudo`)
- and/or a `~/.inputrc` file (user-specific)

  and/or

you're planning to customize the readline library extensively and/or want to make customizations effective for *scripts* too when they call `read -e`:

Add line

```
set completion-ignore-case on
```

to *either* file, depending on whether you want the setting to be effective for *all* users or the *current* user (create the file, if necessary).

A related command that makes completion of file and directory names easier is:

```
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
```

This makes it unnecessary to press Tab *twice* when there is more than one match.

---

**Option B:** Alternatively, you may add Readline commands to your user-specific `~/.bash_profile` file on OS X (or `~/.bashrc` on Linux), by passing them as a *single* argument to the [`bind` builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins):

```
bind "set completion-ignore-case on"
bind "set show-all-if-ambiguous on"
```

Note that `bind` commands in `~/.bash_profile` / `~/.bashrc` take precedence over equivalent commands in either `/etc/inputrc` or `~/.inputrc`.

As implied above, Readline configuration defined this way will *not* take effect in *scripts* that call `read -e` to activate Readline support for reading user input.

Comment: show-all-if-ambiguous is so nice! I often wondered why they made me tab twice to perform that action. thousands of keystrokes saved in my future! thanks!

Comment: Awesome, it even works for `cd` commands. Which solves [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/527559/how-to-make-cd-arguments-case-insensitive) and will be saving me thousands of keystrokes too. :)

Comment: Great point re `show-all-if-ambiguous`. However, since you say "as an alternative", is there actually any benefit to doing this via `bind`, when the `inputrc` files seem to make that unncessary?

Comment: @underscore_d: Good question; please see my updated answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks! On Debian 8.2 I had neither `inputrc`, but I happily created `~/.inputrc` & added these, plus other really useful directives. I guess we're assuming all readers know that `/etc/inputrc`  affects other users (unless the latter override the affected settings)? Just while we're mentioning caveats ;)

Comment: I think that covers everything - thanks for your efforts making a great answer even better!

Answer (score 2):

To avoid changing configuration for all users and to avoid root permissions use the following:

```
if [ ! -a ~/.inputrc ]; then echo '$include /etc/inputrc' > ~/.inputrc; fi
echo 'set completion-ignore-case on' >> ~/.inputrc
```

Then re-login or reload ~/.inputrc