# Make bash's tab-completion case-insensitive

Tags: bash, tab-completion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Case insensitive tab completion in Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/90196/case-insensitive-tab-completion-in-bash)

Is there any way to make the tab-completion in bash case-insensitive? For instance, if I have a file called `Hello.txt` and try to tab-complete it by typing `he` followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd> it will not work. I would have to tab-complete it by typing `He` (note the capital H) and <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Is there any way to set up bash so I don't have to preserve the case when I type it and try to tab-complete it?

Comment: I'm glad to know that this works on Linux, as the other question is OSX-specific, @sathya

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Create a file named `.inputrc` in your home directory, and place this line in it:

```
set completion-ignore-case on
```

Then open a new shell and try it out. If /etc/inputrc exists on your system, you should generally also add the line `$include /etc/inputrc`. But there's no way to make this conditional, so you should only add it if that file exists.

Comment: This will prevent bash from reading the defaults from `/etc/inputrc`, breaking things like navigation with ctrl-left/right. Make sure to add `$include /etc/inputrc` in your `~/.inputrc`.

Comment: You can also use [bind -f ~/.inputrc](http://superuser.com/a/1064223/362931) to reload this change.

Comment: I'm going to incorporate @NicolasMarchildon comment into the answer, because it should be there

Comment: Strangely, it doesn't work for me. Here's my `~/.inputrc`: https://pastebin.com/WVQmrNZu

Comment: @AlexeyPetrenko That looks ok to me. Are there any invisible characters in the file messing things up? Try printing it with `LC_ALL=C cat -vet ~/.inputrc` -- you should see a "$" at the end of each line, but nothing else funny. Also, try `bind -v`, and see what it shows for the `completion-ignore-case` variable. Finally, is there something in another shell init file that might be changing it?