# How to make cd arguments case INsensitive?

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make bash’s tab-completion case-insensitive](https://superuser.com/questions/271530/make-bashs-tab-completion-case-insensitive)

Sometimes while accessing the various directories it happens most of the times that i remember the names or at least part of the names of a directory under our Linux system. But some of the directories are named starting with first character caps or one of the characters in the middle of the name Upper case.

Can anyone suggest how can i make the arguments following cd command case INSENSITIVE, such that if i perform `cd BackupDirectory` or `cd backupdirectory` it could enter the directory name BackupDirectory.

Ofcourse i don't want to screw the things for other users so if the above is possible, is that  possible that the change could be applied just to the session i am using and do not effect other users?

OK, i tried `bind "set completion-ignore-case on"` but this just doesn't work. It just helps in the way if i type `cd b` and [tab] [tab] or [esc] [esc] it fills the directory name ignoring the case. But, what i need is if i do a `cd backupdirectory`, it just ignores the case and enters BackupDirectory on its own.

Comment: Probably not, because in the general case, you might have both `BackupDirectory` **and** `backupdirectory`.

Comment: [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/435127/198070) solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to `~/.inputrc`:

```
set completion-ignore-case on
```

Edit: sorry I just realized this doesn't re-lookup the previous word. To do that, you could make a custom "cd" completion in bash_complete.