# How can I get bash to perform case insensitive tab-completion for my aliases and functions?

Tags: bash, tab-completion, inputrc

I have an alias like this:

```
alias sshUntrusted='ssh -X -C -c blowfish-cbc,arcfour'
```

But when I type

```
$ sshun
```

followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd>, Bash does not complete the alias.

I have put

```
set completion-ignore-case on   #ignore case while completing
```

in my `.bashrc`, and it makes Bash perform case insensitive tab-completion for filenames.

How can I make it complete aliases and functions in a case insensitive manner?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case insensitive tab completion in Bash](http://superuser.com/questions/90196/case-insensitive-tab-completion-in-bash)